# How do I convert a serial number from horizontal to vertical without if else?

Tags: php, math, formula

I am working on a web-page for my company about an on-line survey page, our customer service team will simply input some check-box questions into a database. and my job is to display them on a page and gather the player's answers back to our database.

for example if I have 12 questions in the database, and I need it to be displayed in a table as:

1 5 9 
2 6 10 
3 7 11 
4 8 12

or,  if I have 13 questions, it should be displayed as
1 6 10
2 7 11
3 8 12
4 9 13
5

this can be done with some if else in PHP, but i would like to do it in mathematical ways just to enrich my knowledge.

any suggestion or hints are appreciate if I can pass the total questions(in this case 13) and vertical column counts(in this case 3) in a formula, and it simply return the orders of the numbers in this way  {1, 6, 10, 2, 7, 11, 3, 8, 12, 4, 9, 13, 5}

honestly, I will not rewrite the survey page. I am just curious if this can be done with some math without if/else in the programming.

Comment: If you are using tables you need a count of the rows and do a `if (($row%3) == 0) { echo "</tr><tr>"; }`

Basically every 3th result it will add those and you will get the desired result

Comment: If horizontal self-aligning boxes are ok, too, you can do it with pure CSS. Give the boxes a fixed size and let them "float:left;" in a surrounding container div.

Comment: It's possible, see my answer, no `if`s in sight :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Here's my latest solution for generating the array which is even more mathematical than before:

```
$q = 27;//number of questions
$c = 4;//number of columns
$m =  $q%$c;//modulus
$step = floor($q/$c);
$arr = array();
for ($n=0; $n<$q; $n++){
    $arr[] = 1 + $step*($n%$c) + ($m + $n%$c - abs($m - $n%$c))/2 + floor($n/$c);
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
array(1, 8, 15, 22, 2, 9, 16, 23, 3, 10, 17, 24, 4, 11, 18, 25, 5, 12, 19, 26, 6, 13, 20, 27, 7, 14, 21);
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

```
$q = 13;//number of questions
$c = 3;//number of columns
$mod = array_fill(0, $c, 0);
for ($i=0; $i<($q%$c); $i++){
    $mod[$i] = 1; 
}
$step = floor($q/$c);
$arr = array();
$cum = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
    $cum += @$mod[$i-1];
    $arr[] = 1 + $step*$i + $cum;
}
$next = $arr;
for ($i=1; $i<$step; $i++){
    foreach ($next as $key => $value){
        $next[$key]++;
    }
    $arr = array_merge($arr, $next);
}
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
    $next[$i] = ($next[$i] + 1)*$mod[$i] ;
}
$arr = array_filter(array_merge($arr, $next));
var_dump($arr);
```

The output is:

```
array(1, 6, 10, 2, 7, 11, 3, 8, 12, 4, 9, 13, 5);
```

Here's my solution for generating a table:

```
$q = 27;//number of questions
$c = 4;//number of columns
$cell = '<td>i</td>';
$table = '<table>';
$mod = array_fill(0, $c, 0);
for ($i=0; $i<($q%$c); $i++){
    $mod[$i] = 1; 
}
$step = floor($q/$c);
$arr = array();
$cum = 0;
$table .= '<tr>';
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
    $cum += @$mod[$i-1];
    $num = 1 + $step*$i + $cum;
    $arr[] = $num;
    $table .= str_replace('i', $num, $cell);
}
$table .= '</tr><tr>';
$next = $arr;
for ($i=1; $i<$step; $i++){
    foreach ($next as $key => $value){
        $num = ++$next[$key];
        $table .= str_replace('i', $num, $cell);
    }
    //$arr = array_merge($arr, $next);
    $table .= '</tr><tr>';
}
$table = substr($table, 0 , -4);
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
    $next[$i] = ($next[$i] + 1)*$mod[$i] ;
}
$next = array_filter($next);
$span = $c - count($next);
$ini = '';
$fin = '';
$last = '';
foreach ($next as $key => $value){
    $ini = '<tr>';
    $last .= str_replace('i', $value, $cell);
    $fin = '<td span="'.$span.'">&nbsp;</td></tr>';
}
//$arr = array_merge($arr, $next);
$table .= $ini.$last.$fin.'</table>';
echo $table;
```

With 27 questions and 4 columns, the output is:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>8</td><td>15</td><td>22</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>9</td><td>16</td><td>23</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>10</td><td>17</td><td>24</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>11</td><td>18</td><td>25</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>12</td><td>19</td><td>26</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>13</td><td>20</td><td>27</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>14</td><td>21</td><td span="1">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can, of course, modify the value of `$cell` to insert a link or whatever you want into the table cells.

Comment: You are really a genius, this is really what I was looking for!
and now I realized that this is way too advanced for me to understand! lol

I thought this question will be some easier math like sum up 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  that I can just do (1+10)*10/2

I really appreciate with your help! It is fun to play things with math.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using mod function i.e. '%' and also use array in it. I have a question here. Will the number of column remain 3 ? If so then you can take 3 different array to store the records in order. Then display those in each column. Yes, here you cannot do this by using a single html table, you need to use div for each column.

Answer (score 0):

The below gives the result in the first case as an array. But when all the cells of the matrix do not have value i think one have to use if else statement

```
    <?php
    function lists ($total_cells, $vertical_cols) {
      $total = $total_cells;
     $cols = $vertical_cols;
     $hor = (int)($total/$cols);

     $res = array();
    $j=0;
     $current = 1;
      for($j=1;$j<=$hor;$j++){
     $current = $j;
        for($i = 1; $i<=$cols; $i++) {
          $res[$j][] = $current; 
        $current = $current+$hor;
            }
           }
         return $res;
        }


     ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your checkboxes are stored in an array called `$target`.

```
<?php
$target = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$target = array_chunk($target, 3); //Split the array into chunks of 3.
$result = array_map(function ($el) {
    return implode("</td><td>", $el); //Implode the inner arrays with table cells 
}, $target);
$result = implode("</td></tr><tr><td>", $result); //Implode the outer arrays with table rows.

echo "<table><tr><td>";
echo $result;
echo "</td></tr></table>";
```

You'll get a **[table in groups of three](http://3v4l.org/VJbgW)**.

---

If you want a function that will determine the number of columns, you just change the number "3" in `array_chunk` to the argument of that function :)